# Javascript alert not working from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am generating a javascript alert box from codebehind in asp.net(vb).

The code:

```
            Catch ex As Exception
                MesgBox("Error in uploading file due to following exception" & vbNewLine & ex.ToString)
                trans.Rollback()
            Finally
                conn.Close()
            End Try
```

The mesgbox function is as follows:

```
Private Sub MesgBox(ByVal sMessage As String)
    Dim msgedtble As String = sMessage.Replace("\", "\\")
    msgedtble = msgedtble.Replace(vbNewLine, "\n")
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType,
 "myScripts",
 "<script language='javascript'>alert('" & msgedtble & "');</script>")

End Sub
```

Now when exception is thrown, the following script is appended in the form tag of the client side html :

```
        <script language='javascript'>alert('Error in uploading file due to following exception\nSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_AccountMaster'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AccountMaster'.\nThe statement has been terminated.\n   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)\n   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)\n   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)\n   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)\n   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)\n   at UploadAccountMasterXl.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\\Users\\ssaa\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\Dpp2012\\UploadAccountMasterXl.aspx.vb:line 57');</script>
```

Why is this not appearing in my browser(Firefox)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization` to the top of your file, then try this:

```
Private Sub MesgBox(ByVal sMessage As String)
    Dim serializer as New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim msgedtble As String = serializer.Serialize(sMessage)
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "myScripts",
        "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(" & msgedtble & ");</script>")
End Sub
```

Using JavaScriptSerializer should take care of the linebreaks, single quotes, and everything else we haven't already thought of.

Comment: Also, it's VB.NET, so it should be `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization`, and it should be at the very start of the file

Comment: I believe that JavaScriptSerializer will add the quotes. I am a PHP guy, and I know that json_encode adds the quotes.

Comment: Great Mark! Works Like a gem!

Comment: Fair enough @Mark... as I've not used the class, I really shouldn't have commented! :-)  (And as it apparently works, I'm definitely wrong!)  Will remove my original comment

Comment: @rahulserver please review my answer one last time to confirm that `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization` is correct. I don't have .net or even Windows, so no way to test my answer.

Comment: yes Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization is correct.Just needs to be added to the beginning of vb file.U even do not need to type in. Visual studio automatically hints about it! And Thank you!

Comment: @MarkEirich I am unable to get more than one javascript alert working from this solution. How to get more than one?

Comment: @rahulserver It's hard to say without seeing your code... Are you calling MesgBox multiple times, or are you passing multiple messages to it? If you're calling MesgBox multiple times, you probably have to make sure the second param of Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() is unique instead of being "myScripts" every time. Read carefully at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

Comment: @MarkEirich thanks. I called the Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() with different "myscripts" parameter and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not allow string constants to span line breaks.

In your server-side code, you're going to have to replace the newlines in the error message with "\n".

Comment: I did what u said.Now see the edited script and function. It still is not being rendered.

Comment: You should check the browser error console to see what's happening. The browser will tell you about JavaScript errors; there may be some other characters in the string to escape. *edit* - it looks like there are single-quote characters in the string. You could use double-quotes around it instead, or you could strip out the single quotes, or replace them with "\'".

Comment: Check whether your server-side language has built-in support for encoding JSON. If it does, this will be the best way to encode the string.

Answer (score 1):

To carry on with the answer given by Pointy, your message contains `'` characters, which you need to escape.

Try this...

```
  msgedtble = msgedtble.Replace(vbNewLine, "\n").Replace("'","\'")
```

It is also better to have `type='text/javascript'` rather than `language='javascript'`... although this is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: This answer is still not robust; for example, if there are backslashes in the string... using JavaScriptSerializer is your only safe bet.

Comment: @rahulserver I appreciate the "correct answer", but you can only select one on a question... as you already selected Mark's answer below, I think he deserves the "tick"

Comment: @freefaller You are a true gentleman, conceding the accepted answer, as well as contributing helpful info to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately @Mark, we are few and far between ;-) Plus, as you point out, my answer is not particularly robust