# vb javascript alert

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alert

Here is my code and I was stuck on how to put the alert box:

```
    If Session("prs") <300 Then
   ??????????????
     'Response.Redirect("profile.aspx")
     End IF
```

I want if the "prs" <300 then pop out an alert box and the box is remain on that page. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Technically, this might not a duplicate, but it contains the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274180/javascript-alert-not-working-from-code-behind

Answer (score 0):

this might be what youre looking for:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('this is an alert');</script>");
```

Comment: @Bella: I posted a link as a comment to your question. Did it not help you?

Comment: @Heinzi I have try ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "", "Showalert();", True) but the box din't pop up on the page I want, any advise?